# Box Spout cell height width increase/decrease?

Tags: php, spout

Box Spout cell height  width increase/decrease ??

basically  want to cell width and height increase. read full Box spout documentation. but unable to find solution.

Doc Link : http://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/#styling-cells

Below my code:

```
$style2 = (new StyleBuilder())
                    ->setFontSize(12)
                    ->setFontColor(Color::BLACK)
                    ->setShouldWrapText()
                    ->setCellAlignment(CellAlignment::CENTER)
                    ->setBackgroundColor(Color::LIGHT_GREEN)
                    ->setBorder($border)
                     ->setFormat(200)
                    ->build();
$rowFromValues = WriterEntityFactory::createRowFromArray($value, $style);
 $writer->addRow($rowFromValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not possible with the current version. However, there is [a pull request open](https://github.com/box/spout/pull/715) on GitHub proposing that functionality.

Comment: any other approach for changes cells width and height?